# Окончание в имени (падеж)

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Как верно написать: "*Меня зовут Маша, но дома меня любят звать* **Марусей**" или "*Меня зовут Маша, но дома меня любят звать* **Маруся**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Меня зовут Маша, но дома меня любят звать Маруся/Марусей.**

Из словаря:

**ЗВАТЬ** [именовать; называть] сочетается **с формами именительного и творительного падежей.** Этого мальчика зовут Петя / Петей; Ему было двадцать пять лет, звали его Иваном Ивановичем (Гарш.); Уля не знала фамилии этой девушки, все звали её Люда (Ф.).

Можно заметить, что **И.п.** встречается чаще в предложениях вида: Меня зовут Маша. Но если говорят "можно звать", то **Т.п.** тоже используется довольно часто.

Примеры:

― Позволь, я за тобой поухаживаю, ― сказала девушка. ― Кстати, **меня зовут Маша.** ― А я ― Паша, ― покраснел Пафнутьев. [Виктор Пронин. Банда 8 (2005)]

Воцарилось неловкое молчание. ― **Можно звать просто Сашей…** ― выдавил я из себя заранее приготовленную фразу. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Понедельник начинается в субботу (1964)]

Можно звать и **дядя Вася**, но не стоит.